# How to get a context menu for file system actions in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, contextmenu

Is there any way to get a system context menu for files?

I need to have all the commands from system menu, not only simple operations like copy/paste/rename, but also some non-standard, like Dropbox actions.

I am using Qt 5.x on Windows, but a solution for Mac OS would be useful, too. If the answer requires a library independent of Qt, that is ok too.

Comment: Clarify in the question some information about your platform (or maybe you need this feature to be cross-platform), the answer really depends on it.

Comment: As far as I know there is no such function in Qt. You need to find another library or implement this manually.

Comment: +1 for this question. It might be Windows-specific solution for me (there always is #ifdef), but cross-platform solution would be the greatest!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668456/how-to-show-windows-explorer-context-right-click-menu, you'll definitely have to use Winapi.

Answer (score 4):

Qt does not provide such feature. But you could use native API for each platform. See

> [How do you show the Windows Explorer context menu from a C# application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451287/how-do-you-show-the-windows-explorer-context-menu-from-a-c-sharp-application)

for getting Windows explorer menu.

Comment: It should be noted that, although the linked question is about C#, the answer to it is pure C++.