# Disambiguation: coding a Shell Extensions for the context menu of Windows Explorer.exe vs Use Shell ContextMenu in Your Applications

Tags: c#, windows, contextmenu, windows-shell-extension-menu

I struggled for hours trying to find information on the second point: **Use Shell ContextMenu in Your Applications**. There are tons of discussion on how to **code a Shell Extensions and add it to the context menu of Explorer.exe**.

So, where can I find informations on both those different stuffs?

Answer (score 0):

Most common Tag: [[windows-shell-extension-menu]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-shell-extension-menu), [[contextmenu]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/contextmenu), [explorer], [[shell-extension]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/shell-extensions)

#### Use Shell ContextMenu in Your Applications

[How to show Windows Explorer context (right click) menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10668456/how-to-show-windows-explorer-context-right-click-menu#10669690)

[External example from codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4025/Use-Shell-ContextMenu-in-your-applications)

#### Coding a Shell Extensions for the context menu of Windows Explorer.exe

[External example from codeproject.com](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)